# Academic Genealogy

Tags: publications

[Mathematics Genealogy project](http://www.genealogy.ams.org/) has existed for many years. It currently  has 170,235 records as of 15 May, 2013. I understand there are many computer scientists in that database since computer science is generally considered a branch of mathematics.

I have found several other similar efforts. For example, the [Academic genealogy of theoretical physicists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_genealogy_of_theoretical_physicists) Wiki page consists of about 100 theoretical physicists. I cannot find Physics Genealogy project in general. A [Chemical Genealogy Database](http://www.scs.illinois.edu/~mainzv/Web_Genealogy/) does not appear to have built a very large database.

My questions are:

- Are there genealogy project for other disciplines?
- Is there a general academic genealogy project somewhere? If yes, where? If not, are there efforts to construct it?

Comment: So you want to find the 'parent' which would tie together all of the other genealogy projects?

Comment: @earthling Yes, if there is one. So, I don't have to Google everywhere.

Comment: This could be one such starting point. I don't think there is a definitive source though. http://academictree.org/

Comment: The [Mathematics Genealogy Project](http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/) is already broader than math. It touches many disciplines related to math in contemporary academia and, as you go back in time, includes a wide portion of academic work. 1000 years ago my academic ancestors were a bunch of bishops. The difference between mathematics, philosophy, and theology was not always very clear or very large.

Comment: This is a question more on mathematics and physics rather than academia in general.

Comment: @Axel Please pay attention to my question _•Are there genealogy project for **other disciplines**?_

Comment: *Mathematics Genealogy project has existed for many years.* - Citation needed.

Comment: @LeonMeier [the project went online there in fall 1997.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_Genealogy_Project)

Answer (score 6):

I believe [Academic Tree](http://academictree.org/) qualifies as a general academic genealogy project. It includes the fields of:

> Neuroscience, Experimental Psychology, Linguisitcs, Primatology, History,
>   Philosophy, Music, Law, Theology, Economics, Advertising, Ingestive Behavior,
>   Physics, Chemistry, Oceanography, Drosophila Genetics,
>   Fission, Yeast Genetics, Mycology and Fungal Genetics, Evolutionary
>   Biology, Marine Ecology, Terrestrial Ecology, Developmental Biology, Cell
>   Biology, Telomere and Telomerase, Infectious Disease, Neuropathology,
>   Computational Biology, Science and Techology Studies, Biomechanics

I think the [neurotree](http://neurotree.org/neurotree/) subtree is the largest of the areas covered with 40,000 people. It allows me to trace my academic linage back to Jesus Christ (thanks to the philosophy tree) in a mere 88 steps.

Comment: [The Mathematical Genealogy Project](http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/) has well over 100,000 so it is definitely larger.

Comment: @BenjaminMakoHill I don't understand your comment. Why does the number matter in terms of answering the question?

Comment: I think I misinterpreted your answer. You said that neutreeo was the largest with 40,000 but it seemed, in your original text, that you were claiming that neurotree was largest genealogical database on the Internet, not the largest subarea covered by the Academic Tree website. I edited your answer to try to clear this up. If my edits are indeed correct, you can ignore my comment.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub I am wondering about the engineering disciplines.

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a computer science offshoot of the mathematics project, but it's disappeared!  I was on both, but only put my PhD students on the CS one.  It was a pain.  There may have been issues e.g. about multiple supervisor, disputed supervision, policing?

Comment: I don't think multiple supervisor would be an issue. There are math PhDs with multiple advisors in the math project. My real question is, why math is successful but other fields are not that successful?

Comment: @scaaahu If you look at http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/acknowledgments.php the answer to why the Math Geneology Project is still around looks like "money." Mostly raised from individual contributors.

Comment: @BSteinhurst Thanks for the info. I just look at the last section: To the order of FLT (FWT), etc. I agree money is one of the factors. Now, my question is, there is no or not enough money from contributors for other fields? Engineering seems to be more wealthy than others. This is still a puzzle to me.

Comment: @scaaahu I think you are underestimating the amount of work that goes into collecting that money. Talk to any fundraiser and they will tell you it is a nontrivial task.

Answer (score 1):

Wikidata collects [doctoral advisor relationships](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P184) between reseachers (among many other kinds of relationships). By now there are 900 such relationships<sup>1</sup> but I would not be suprised if people start to import data from other academic genealogy projects.

---

<sup>1</sup>[Try SPARQL query](https://query.wikidata.org/) `SELECT (COUNT(*) AS ?c) { ?s p:P184 ?o  }` to get current numbers. Anyone more familiar with SPARQL can surely query a distribution among academic disciplines.

Comment: Does this require both researchers to meet wikipedia's notability standards? If so, it would only record a small fraction of all such relationships.

Comment: [Wikidata's notability standards](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Notability) are less strict. I'd guess at least all PhD's having advised another PhD can be included.

Comment: @Jakob standards are less strict, but "has advised a PhD" would probably still fall well below their threshold.